# Find complexe jquery selector

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not an expert in Jquery.  I'd like to get the id of a specific parent selector.

My page contains the following

```
<p>
getting this    <input id="comment16" type="button" value="Comment" disabled="">
                <div class="form" style="">
                    <form id="comment-form" method="post" action="/post/index.php/comment/create?post_id=16">
                        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span>are required.</p>
                        <div id="comment-form_es_" class="errorSummary" style="display:none">
                            <p>Please fix the following input errors:</p>
                            <ul><li>dummy</li></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="required" for="comment_comment">  Comment
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input id="comment_comment" type="text" name="comment[comment]" maxlength="140" size="60">
                            <div id="comment_comment_em_" class="errorMessage" style="display:none"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row buttons">
From here                   <p> <input id="save" type="button" value="Create"> </p>    
                            <p> <input id="cancelcomment" type="button" value="Cancel"></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
</p>
```

I tried this

```
$('body').on('click','#save',function(e) {
            var $thisClicked = $(this);
            var parameter = $thisClicked.attr("id");
            $("#comment-form").submit(function(e) {
                var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var parameter = $thisClicked.parent('div').parent('form').parent('div').closest('input').attr('id');
                parameter = parameter.replace('comment','');

....
```

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: are you trying to submit the form when `#save` is clicked ? `$().submit(function(){})` is an event handler for the form submit event not an instuction to submit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // Gets the closest element in the ancestry matching the selector
  var $form = $this.closest(".form");
  // Gets the preceding sibling element
  var $commentInput = $form.prev();
  alert($commentInput.attr("id"));
});
```

[closest docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) | [prev docs](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Pretty cool stuff. I mostly just googled for it

Comment: i want to get the id   comment16

Comment: And this should do it

Comment: @klark Sorry, now it should do it. Before it just got the element

Comment: when I alert(commentInput)   it displays [object Object]

Comment: commentInput is still the input object. if you want the id, look at the line I alerted

Comment: Thanks TMP for your patience !

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to perform form submit inside button click try:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $form = $this.closest(".form"); 
  $commentInput = $form.prev();   
    parameter = $commentInput.children().attr('id');
    parameter = parameter.replace('comment','');
    alert(parameter);
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/954UD/)

Else you can bind your event on form submit, then you have to change your button type to submit.